# How to decide whether to un-wiki questions/answers posted in rep-denial era

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, moderator-tools

Last year, we decided to stop automatically convert questions to Community Wiki. Relevant MSE thread: [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940).

I think many of these auto-converted questions should be reverted to full questions again, especially the ones that were converted for having 30 answers.

We should do this for questions that are:

- Technical
- Do not appear to have been converted into a community post (the original question is still there)
- Do not have a close/reopen controversy

I think this process should be done manually, over time, via moderator flags.

---

Here are some examples of ones that I think should be restored ... These examples may not be the best, I am mostly asking about what criteria we should use to decide whether a question ought to be reverted to regular question/answer status:

- [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commit)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
- [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)
- [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)
- [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)
- [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer)

Comment: Your title is promising (although *rep-denial era* had me cringe for a while), but your question does not actually elaborate on *why* CW should be undone for the questions you mention. *How to decide* indeed, so how did you choose these?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm actually asking the question. How should we decide?

Comment: Still you submit a list of candidates. What are we supposed to do? Run arbitrary predicates on all the candidates and apply arbitrary coefficients to the results? Surely you chose these questions for a reason, can you explain it?

Comment: Neither of these is a great question in my book - i.e. a question that is born out of a substantial amount of effort and research. Not saying that is bad - I've asked such questions myself - but do we really need to change the rules to retroactively reward them with more points? Hardly.

Comment: Just looking at your first example in the list: the question had 17 edits, not one of them from the OP. The top answer had 11 edits, only one of them from the OP. How is that not the *perfect scenario* of when community wiki *should* be used? It's clearly a community effort.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why we should do this. What benefit will we receive from doing this? You are certainly free to do what you will on your own time, but I just don't understand why anyone would spend time on this.

Answer (score 21):

The original theory behind triggering auto-CW at 30 answers was twofold:

1. encourage folks to read and improve existing answers rather than adding yet another one in cases where the topic had been thoroughly covered already.
2. remove reputation from the equation entirely for questions that were... uh, not really *questions* so much as *discussions*.

We've kinda moved away from that theory, mostly because no one understood it to begin with but also because we've gotten a lot better about straight-up *deleting* questions that fall into category #2 before they run amok and destroy us all.

That said, some do remain. I would not recommend unwikiing them outside of exceptional circumstances where a handful of actual *answers* have emerged, and not always even then - more on that in a bit. Instead, vote to close and/or delete them. In those rare cases where the discussion itself has some historical value, flag and request a moderator apply a Historical Lock to the thread - but still vote to delete first, just in case the moderator disagrees.

For questions in Category #1, you can flag and request that a moderator unwiki the thread - but **first try to clean up the answers a bit.** Downvote and vote to delete<sup>*</sup> answers that are short and repetitive, flag things that aren't answers at all, do some editing to the top answers to make sure they're comprehensive enough to not need dozens of follow-up answers clarifying or covering minutia. See if you can get the volume of not-deleted answers down to some reasonable number - *at least* less than 30.

In some cases, you'll find that the *only* reason the question is still around **is** that it was wikied and folks started editing the top answers instead of posting new ones. These are easily recognized, as the top few answers will be heavily edited and *quite* comprehensive, while the rest will be essentially things that *should* have been edits - errata, individual list items, etc. There's a special lock reason for these as well - flag and request that a moderator apply the "**Wiki Answers**" lock to the question, thereby preserving the ability of future readers to add their own findings via edits rather than posting yet more answers that no one will read.

<sup>*<sub>You'll need to earn a bit more rep to get the privilege to perform this step.</sub></sup>

Comment: consider moving this to MSE, as SO seems to be not the only site that may benefit from this guidance

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253262/request-to-undo-auto-cw-on-answers-edited-over-years/257253#257253), @gnat.