# Another user merged my code from GitHub into my answer and now my name isn't attached to it

Tags: support, bug, community-wiki, attribution, user-card

The answer in question is this one: [Creating a memory leak with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java/6471947#6471947)

In response to lots of people in the comments asking for a code example, I wrote some code in a Gist. The code is about 130 lines and is wholly unnecessary to understand my answer. I edited my answer to add a link to the Gist, but I didn't paste in the whole code, because (IMO) that would have detracted from the basic point of my answer.

Earlier today, user igaurav copy/pasted the entire contents of my Gist into my answer. I just rolled back to the previous revision.

However, the credit on the answer now reads "3 revs, 2 users 84% igaurav". That seems unfair, especially since 100% of the content that was ever in the answer was written by me.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I get that this is a community wiki post we're talking about, but it does seem like rolling back edits should quite simply count those edits out of the contribution total, since you're effectively nope-ing them.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. It is essentially a workaround for hijacking community wiki posts.

Comment: While this would be an implementation nightmare, the percentage in CW posts should be based on the current content.  So if someone adds a line, they should get credit for that line (in terms of a share of the contribution).  If someone later removes that line, my contribution no longer exists, so shouldn't have any ownership in the post anymore.

Comment: Can you do your own runaround by re-adding and then re-deleting the code?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Hmmm... that might be an option. It would be nice if I could get a more authoritative suggestion to do that before I do, though -- that feels like a pretty spammy edit to make.

Comment: For the record: I just tried it, and re-adding the code and re-deleting it didn't help. :-(

Comment: "A workaround to force _Klingon diff_ display a major contributor as an author (tested [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260)) is for the user to add then remove a dummy text with sufficient amount of line breaks..." ([Community wiki post not displaying majority author correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130820/165773))

Comment: @gnat: Thanks! That does in fact work. It's still super annoying, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in an [answer to similar question at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130820/165773),

> A workaround to force *Klingon diff* display a major contributor as an author... is for the user to add then remove a dummy text with sufficient amount of line breaks:
>
> ```
>     <!--
>     CW attribution algorithm work-around: 
>     See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65541
>
>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
>     ...put sufficient amount of lines here
>     -->
> ```

This is quite painful but luckily, they [stopped using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227290/165773) a while ago, so currently this harms only old posts.

Comment: Ooh, thanks for the link to that CW change. I guess that means that this whole question can be non-CW now? (It only became CW when it was linked from Reddit and got dozens of answers, causing the magic >30 answer threshold to get tripped.) I've flagged to see if that's possible.

Comment: @DanielPryden well, that change only saves _newer_ questions. As for older ones, it's a bit more complicated, see [How to decide whether to un-wiki questions/answers posted in rep-denial era](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288022/839601)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the countermeasures concerning the % contribution, I think it's also appropriate to flag a moderator about the copyright violation so they can send the user a corresponding nastygram reminding them not to plagiarize and that when posting content that isn't their original work they need permission from the author / rights holder.

Something along the lines of

> I am the author of code added without permission to my answer by (offending user), and I do not intend to make that code available under a CC BY-SA license.  The actual license is clearly posted on github.  Please remove that revision from the site and speak to the user about plagiarism.

Stack Exchange has a legal process for compelling removal of copyrighted work (DMCA takedown), but I suspect because it involves not only your code but also your answer, they may be able to act without extensive legal documentation.

Comment: That's a good point about reposting code being a potential licensing violation. I don't think a "nastygram" is necessarily warranted in this case, since I'd like to assume that the other user acted in good faith, but it is a good warning to be aware of. I think a polite note to the user in question would probably be sufficient.