# Is it possible that an editor of a question completely replaces the original author?

Tags: discussion, answers

If someone does many edits to an answer given by someone else, can this person be listed below the answer as author, replacing the original author? I don't mean the "edited by" tag next to the author, I mean a complete replacement.

Comment: No. Why would someone do many edits to someone else's answers anyway?

Comment: So it's technically not possible? The original author of an answer stays the author no matter how many edits someone else does to the answer?

Comment: Again, why would someone do "many" edits to an answer which was not theirs? It is not a case of being "technically not possible" it is a case of "there's no good reason to even attempt that, and it would be plain flat out wrong and unthinkable if the system were to do that".

Comment: This _may_ happen, if the post is [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (thus, owned by the community, and not any single user).

Comment: I can see your point.

Comment: IIRC a post will turn into a community wiki by itself once it's edited enough. I don't know how up to date that memory is though.

Comment: @deceze - There is no automatic conversion to CW anymore.

Comment: @Martin Ah, so those were the good old days...

Comment: @BillWoodger Altruism? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have made a ginormous rewrite of this fantastic answer and will see whether or not I become the "owner" of this answer. Some additional text, like this gratuitous sentence here, should improve my chances of this happening.

Comment: This is not a good thing.

Comment: @jjack - Why not? The answer is community wiki.

Comment: So I can select if I want a post to be community wiki or sole ownership?

Comment: The original author can select this for an answer. Only moderators can select this for questions as it also affects all answers to that question.

Comment: So if someone with enough rep wants to high jack my answer, he can? All reputation to him then?

Comment: No. Community Wiki posts don't accrue any reputation anyway and only moderators (not high rep users) can force an answer to become CW.

Comment: Is that the case for every Stackexchange site?

Comment: @deceze - I would have thought that should be sufficient! Clearly not.

Comment: @jjack - Yes AFAIK the rules are the same for all.

Comment: @jjack See how the post is attributed now: "67% Martin"...

Comment: @deceze: I'm on an Android device, I can't see the 67%. But it serves the purpose,  considering Martin's answers.

Comment: I'll have to guess who gets pinged here. I see "2 revs, 2 users 67%" with @MartinSmith's name, so assumed original plus two revisions, with original from deceeze. Yet clicking on edited by doesn't show that.

Comment: @BillWoodger - Yes the ownership is never really changed except for the name shown under the post. It will always show up in my list of answers irrespective of how radically it is changed by other people.

Comment: @deceze (I cunningly realised I could make the points in two parts and ping both of you that way). Isn't offering up CW for this a bit of a sleight-of-hand? CW is *designed* to be edited by other people (and, sure, many times would be possible) but do you really think that is what OP was asking about?

Comment: @BillWoodger - The question was `Is it possible that an editor of a question completely replaces the original author?` - The answer is yes. But the only time this is possible is with CW.

Comment: Thanks. I missed it while it was happening. So you asked (and made it CW, which notification is posted first) and then Deceeze changed it, and... what happened? Did it then show Deceeze? Why does it now show you?

Comment: OK, you answered the Title. I missed that.

Comment: @BillWoodger - It didn't show Deceeze - Somewhat surprisingly as at least 90% of the current content was contributed by him. But if he [uses the work around here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289930/73226) it will switch.

Comment: That was fun. Managed to post it as an answer.  
Thanks for the link. I now see that the 66% refers to the amount of material (I'd previously assumed number of edits as percentage of total). Now curious as to what "revs" means. Is it "revisors" as in editors, rather than "revisions"? I know one way of checking.

Comment: Successfully stolen, even though I rolled back to Deceeze's.

Comment: The amount contributed algorithm seems to be counting words.

Comment: @bjb568 the [Klingon diff](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I1GY5.jpg) counts line breaks