# What to do with close/open 'wars'?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574241/are-there-real-world-uses-of-sun-misc-unsafe has recently seen a flood of close/reopen/undelete etc votes (it was posted in a blog post and social media) and now it seems like we're in the beginning of a open/close war.

I have closed voted this as "too broad",

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

but some people seem to think it would be best to remain open for historical purposes. Shouldn't it be closed but maybe not deleted? Isn't that how historical off-topic questions are 'maintained'?? Also how do we proceed from here to avoid a continued 'open/close' battle?

Comment: I think it's still possibly worth a debate... I've historical locked it as I feel that's appropriate going forward and will stop the effects of the influx of reddit/HN traffic for now etc... there may be other opinions/options.

Comment: Open for historical significance is nonsense. You can lock for historical significance though.

Comment: What is the _problem_ in keeping a (perhaps) off-topic/too broad question on the site, once it's already been asked, answered, voted on and viewed plenty of times?

Comment: @CodeCaster it sets precedence that these are still allowed to be asked today.

Comment: That's what's always being used as argument. Can't we deal with that when such an occasion arises? I don't feel like deleting useful content.

Comment: @CodeCaster you aren't deleting "useful content", but putting it in their proper place. How about I deliver a masterwork statue to your house and plant it in the very front of your door in a way nobody can pass through? You wouldn't be very happy, right?

Comment: Options are deletion or historical lock, and I don't care which for this question. But leaving it open is not an option, and now it's locked.

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for the upcoming *Deprecated* feature.

Comment: Yes, @Josh, that anology is just as nice as Braiam's. This is the internet. There's no physycal limit in this regard, it's not taking up space for another question.

Comment: Huh, somehow I missed that Braiam had already made the analogy, @CodeCaster. I guess I'll delete mine. The point stands, however: stuff may not take up _storage_ space, but it takes up _viewing_ space (only so many search results can fit on a screen), and it takes up _time_ (is this question going to have the tidbit of info I need?). It gets in the way of trying to do other things.

Comment: Maybe not the most helpful comment but I find closing is contagious.  One person votes to close and a slew follow closely after.  I would hope SE errs on the side of not closing...

Comment: @DaveKaye closing generally tends to be _slightly_ contagious, but in this particular case what you observe is better known as ["meta effect"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601). Note how [reopening appears also contagious](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5574241/revisions) which is indeed almost never the case

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're asking a lot of questions here...

#### What to do with open/close wars?

Let 'em burn out. You only get one close or reopen vote per question, so eventually the people who care about a question will have all voted and its status will be resolved as either open or closed.

#### Shouldn't it be closed but maybe not deleted?

Maaaaybe. If a question is clearly inappropriate but has, for instance, a brilliant, timeless answer... Then keeping it around in some form is polite: breaking The Internet by deleting those rare gems that shouldn't have ended up here but somehow did anyway isn't cool.

That said, this is a poor way to maintain an important question; any closed question is *eligible* for deletion; keeping it on death row because you don't have the guts to say "guilty" or "innocent" is just asking for trouble. Note that there are currently no limits on how many times one person can vote to *delete* a question, or how long a vote can remain in the system... So the balance is weighted heavily in favor of closed questions being eventually deleted. Thus, **if you don't think a question should be deleted, then you do not want to leave it closed.**

#### Isn't that how historical off-topic questions are 'maintained'?

A "historical significance" lock exists for this purpose; feel free to kick off a meta discussion for any question you think deserves this. Questions locked in this way cannot be deleted or flagged or modified in any way; it is explicitly intended to preserve the state of a question as if it were frozen in time.

OTOH, if a question actually works *as a question* - that is, it's about programming and provides information of value to working programmers and might even benefit from additional answers as time goes on - then no, closing it makes no sense. Leave it open (perhaps [Protect](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/) it) and don't worry about it. There are exceptions to every rule; use your judgement.

#### Also how do we proceed from here to avoid a continued 'open/close' battle?

Stop worrying about it and start trusting your peers a little bit. Democracy is messy, but on the whole it does usually work. The day we become so afraid of our peers that we stop listening to them is the day this whole enterprise goes down the tubes.

If you're concerned that folks are getting frustrated by the battle, then start a discussion here on meta regarding the merits of the question (or lack thereof). Often, giving folks a place to lay out their arguments in depth can do more to resolve a dispute than any other measure. Yes, it will be messy as well... Don't be afraid of a little dirt.

#### Related:

- [Community-led deletionism: a protocol for sanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity)
- [Do not lock old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112910/do-not-lock-old-questions/112935#112935)
- [We could use better management of popular, but "bad" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257605/we-could-use-better-management-of-popular-but-bad-questions/257653#257653)
- [How to decide whether to un-wiki questions/answers posted in rep-denial era](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288020/how-to-decide-whether-to-un-wiki-questions-answers-posted-in-rep-denial-era/288022#288022)

Comment: I think that in its current form it shouldn't be maintained in any way or form. There are several questions that can be answered with those answers instead of keeping a itemized *single* list of stuff. That's the most desirable outcome and what should be done instead of the plethora of locking poor questions because of the answers. There are enough experts in Java that could do this, efficiently without the intervention of a moderator. That's what should spawn of this discussion, not a poor man solution like "locking".

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on this specific question; for all I know, this is one of those crazy decisions that Java programmers actually have to consider at some point in their career. Therefore, I follow my own advice and defer to those who care.

Comment: @Braiam 0.02% of open questions on the site are locked in one way or another. That is hardly an epidemic. You haven't made a case for how having this post remain in a *historically locked* state would cause harm to the site as a whole. It would indeed be very useful for the relevant information to be be copied to more suitable questions, where users are more likely to find it when they need it. However it's not necessary to delete the original question for that to happen.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I won't repeat in a comment what I've said [in an answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296787/372643), but historical locks are one of the worst things on SO. That said, I'd err on the side of leaving these questions open: this has visibly been useful or of interest to a number of users (more than many other questions), why not leave things be once in a while...

Comment: @JeremyBanks that number should be in 0. Nothing that is really important hasn't been asked and answered before. Why would must keep the worse of the internet along with the bad? The solution is there: ask several questions with those answers, the useful stuff stays in the right way, and that way can also helps to more people instead of just distracting idle through reading something that may or may not be the best solution available for their problems (and as far I understand, everything that can be done with unsafe, is already available trough the safe(?) API)

Comment: Y'all are reenacting a conversation had years ago. If you're not gonna read the related links I helpfully included, then please take it to [chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: @Shog9 It's true some of this is mentioned in the links you posted, but there was never any definitive agreement between all the participants. The problem is that the general mood has changed over the years, and there's no consensus on how to clean up some questions, or whether some of those questions even need to be closed and dealt with at all.

Comment: @Shog9 `You only get one close or reopen vote per question` does that mean I vote to close and a question is closed and then the OP fixes it I cannot vote to reopen?

Comment: @NathanOliver You get one close vote, and one reopen vote, per question: you can do each exactly once per question.  So, yes, you can vote to reopen the fixed question.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: There was never and can never be a single unified consensus that applies to all questions past and present, @Bruno - expecting otherwise is naive. Thus, we still discuss [meta-tag:specific-question]s here on meta and vote according to our conscience. Feel free to raise a discussion for anything here that you disagree with... But do it in its own thread, not in the comments here; this is unlikely to be widely read and the venue does not allow much in the way of nuanced response.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't a question and/or answer with lots of upvotes protect a question from being deleted, even if it is closed?

Comment: No. They get a bit harder to delete, but as long as a question is closed it can still be deleted, @cimmanon.

Comment: 1. curious as to what happens during a close/reopen war? If I voted once for reopening and it was closed. Can I vote for reopening again?! 2. does a reopened answer need more close votes? or each time it's just 5? And eventually an answer could have 120 closed votes 125 open votes which will make it open right?

Comment: No, no, yes. @Honey

Answer (score 19):

This question is essentially this:

> I have a hammer, what can I break with it?

Everyone that knows what a hammer is, knows that the amount of things that can be broken with it is endless (Grand Theft Auto players know this very well).

That's not the sort of question you want Stack Overflow (or SE, for that matter) to cater for. You will have a new answer each time someone knows a cool way to use the method in some "clever" way. This is the very definition of too broad and the precedent it sets by leaving it undeleted (and therefore bending our guidelines to people that neither keep SO running nor know what it takes to keep it that way) is very worrying.

My take on the matter is to **keep it deleted**. If someone instead asks the questions those answers are supposed to answer (and apparently there are a bunch of 10k users that can do so), instead of just an itemized list of things you can do with it, that would be desirable.

---

> Why would locking not solve the problem?

Because locking doesn't solve problems. It's like putting a "DO NOT PASS" message on a shaky building that can collapse at a moment's notice. That won't prevent people from accessing the building *if they want to*, nor prevent the building from ultimately collapsing and shallowing up innocents passerby in the process (along with whoever was inside). For that, it is preferable to destroy the building yourself, in a controlled manner. That would remove the dangers it would pose for people unaware of dangers and allow you to give ending to something that was destined to end.

Comment: Re: "I have a hammer, what can I break with it?": Given that the question is really "I have a hammer, what can I use it for?", I find it disconcerting that you apparently think all uses of hammers are for breaking things. ;-)

Comment: @ruakh well, [what about a little guy with big knife and a smile](http://funnystack.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Motivational-Posters-68.jpg)? Either way you know they are up to no good.

Comment: A historical lock removes the question from listings throughout the site. Regular contributors aren't going to randomly come across this question. Visitors who see it (through a direct link) are usually coming from off-site, usually won't be contributors to Stack Overflow, and will immediately see the banner that this is not an on-topic question for the site. The risk of setting a terrible precedent by leaving a bad question open is much higher than the risk of setting a terrible precedent by leaving it historically locked.

Comment: @JeremyBanks instead of keeping it locked, because is a bad question, **ask the right ones**. That would give you the possibility to keeping the information around in a way people will actually find to solve their problems. Keeping this because it breaks the internet, just cause SO to being broken, because the model which made SO so famous isn't being followed.

Comment: @Braiam now outside attention has slowed and it's been up for debate on meta and people have aired their views... the question is no longer locked... tbh I'm not overly bothered what happens to the question - it just needed a small time out for people to voice themselves and not get hammered by a combined reddit/hn/meta effect...

Comment: @JonClements thanks for that. I really appreciate it. Maybe instead of answering questions I should just search for locked questions and extract the answers in some more productive way that actually helps people to find solutions to their problems.

Answer (score 6):

What seems 'interesting' to me about this question is that it's in the category of 'lots of votes, but (perhaps) not what we want around here any more.' That makes it hard to resolve a dispute by community deletion, which is one of the dispute resolution possibilities.

To me, this questions faults are that it asks for (a) a list (b) opinions, and (c) that asking about the *entire* 'Unsafe' domain is just too broad. So if it reopens again, I'd vote to close it.

So, I'm not sure that this is a great candidate for democracy in action; in the past, diamonds have intervened in these cases of poor questions with high vote counts. But if the #9 Shog wants to leave it out there, he represents the voice behind the curtain.

Comment: And it got the exact kind of fragmented and partially outdated list which is the reason we don't do lists. Same for opinions and everybody picking their own little corner to hint at something to look at.

Comment: I'm not sure Shog wants to leave it that way. Just that he doesn't have say in the matter, and just deffer to the people that cares.

Comment: BTW, it has been reopened again...

Comment: and closed again. [It is getting messier](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5574241/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

SO works best with narrow, practical problems.  Your question is too broad; so I'll answer a narrow, practical issue.  How to deal with just that question.

Start spawning better questions based on it.

The question is too broad, not bad.  Start spawning or finding a set of FAQs that cover each narrow part of the non-API.  If you need the material, steal parts of the best answers in that question (with attribution back).

"How do I use sun.misc.unsafe.blah?" might even be too broad, but it at least gets closer.  You can even try leading questions (after all, you already have an answer), like "how do I use sun.misc.unsafe.blah to froble my buzz?".  Then solve it.

Another interesting set of questions would be changes in sun.misc.unsafe between versions of Java.

A tag, grouping this stuff together -- sun-misc-unsafe -- might even be justified (I'm not up on what makes a good tag, but sun-misc-unsafe looks searchable, you can be an expert on it, and other than it being tied to particular versions of the JVM (which supports multiple languages) it isn't very meta).

Kill it, and take its stuff.  Well, take its stuff **first**, then kill it.